# How to stop backtracking and end the recursion in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm currently learning SWI-Prolog. I want to implement a function factorable(X) which is true if X can be written as `X = n*b.`
This is what I've gotten so far:

```
isTeiler(X,Y) :- Y mod X =:= 0.

hatTeiler(X,X) :- fail,!.  
hatTeiler(X,Y) :- isTeiler(Y,X), !; Z is Y+1, hatTeiler(X,Z),!.

factorable(X) :- hatTeiler(X,2).
```

My problem is now that I don't understand how to end the recursion with a fail without backtracking. I thought the cut would do the job but after `hatTeiler`fails when both arguments are equal it jumps right to `isTeiler` which is of course true if both arguments are equal. I also tried using `\+` but without success.

Comment: if you put cut before the fail, it will be freeze the backtracking.

Comment: Ohh wow, I really did not see that. But it works. Thank you. Can you briefly explain to me why I have to put it there?

Comment: Use of cuts this way, though, is usually a sign that your predicate design isn't as good as it should be. What you want to do is be precise in your conditions. For example, if you really intend `hatTeiler(X,Y)` to apply when `X` is greater than `Y` then you should include that condition in the body of the predicate: `... :- X > Y, isTeiler(Y, X), ...`. Without the condition, this could run away if `X < Y` since you keep increasing the second argument. You shouldn't need any cuts for this problem. Anyway, your code, when working, always succeeds since every number is its own factor.

Comment: @Anker Ok,I add that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put cut before the fail, it will be freeze the backtracking.
The cut operation freeze the backtracking , if prolog cross it.
Actually when prolog have failed, it backtracks to last cut.
for example :

```
a:- b,
    c,!,
    d,
    e,!,
    f.
```

Here, if b or c have failed, backtrack do not freeze.
if d or f have failed, backtrack Immediately freeze, because before it is a cut
if e have failed , it can backtrack just on d

I hope it be useful

Comment: Now I finally understood the principle of cuts, that makes sense. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you add cuts to end a recursion but this is usually done by making rule heads more specific or adding guards to a clause.

E.g. a rule:

```
x_y_sum(X,succ(Y,1),succ(Z,1)) :-
  x_y_sum(X,Y,Z).
```

will never be matched by `x_y_sum(X,0,Y)`. A recursion just ends in this case.

Alternatively, a guard will prevent the application of a rule for invalid cases.

```
hatTeiler(X,X) :- fail,!.
```

I assume this rule should prevent matching of the rule below with equal arguments. It is much easier just to add the inequality of X and Y as a conditon:

```
hatTeiler(X,Y) :-
  Y>X,
  isTeiler(Y,X),
  !;
  Z is Y+1,
  hatTeiler(X,Z),
  !.
```

Then hatTeiler(5,5) fails automatically. (*)

You also have a disjunction operator `;` that is much better written as two clauses (i drop the cuts or not all possibilities will be explored):

```
hatTeiler(X,Y) :- % (1)
  Y > X,
  isTeiler(Y,X).
hatTeiler(X,Y) :- % (2)
  Y > X,
  Z is Y+1,
  hatTeiler(X,Z).
```

Now we can read the rules declaratively:

(1) if Y is larger than X and X divides Y without remainder, `hatTeiler(X,Y)` is true. 
(2) if Y is larger than X and (roughly speaking) hatTeiler(X,Y+1) is true, then hatTeiler(X, Y) is also true.

Rule (1) sounds good, but (2) sounds fishy: for specific X and Y we get e.g.: `hatTeiler(4,15)` is true when `hatTeiler(4,16)` is true. If I understand correctly, this problem is about divisors so I would not expect this property to hold. Moreover, the backwards reasoning of prolog will then try to deduce `hatTeiler(4,17)`, `hatTeiler(4,18)`, etc. which leads to non-termination. I guess you want the cut to stop the recursion but it looks like you need a different property.

Coming from the original property, you want to check if X = N * B for some N and B. We know that `2 <= N <= X` and X mod N = 0. For the first one there is even a built-in called `between/2` that makes the whole thing a two-liner:

```
hT(X,B) :-
   between(2, X, B),
   0 is (X mod B).


?- hT(12,X).
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 6 ;
X = 12.
```

Now you only need to write your own between and you're done - all without cuts.

(*) The more general hasTeiler(X,X) fails because `is` (and `<`) only works when the right hand side (both sides) is variable-free and contains only arithmetic terms (i.e. numbers, +, -, etc).